# How to get balance history of a bitcoin address using BCOIN node

Tags: address, bcoin

Is there any way to get history balance of an address. Balance is unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs). 
I am using BCOIN node. 
Bcoin has given a API for /coin/address/:address but it is giving current balance as a result instead of history.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the docs](http://bcoin.io/api-docs/index.html#get-coins-by-addresses), you're using the HTTP api incorrectly.

Try this in your terminal. Make sure to define or change the `$url` variable.

```
address0='RQKEexR9ZufYP6AKbwhzdv8iuiMFDh4sNZ';
address1='RHpAA3ZmmmWF6FW8qSfaEvh1jR1nUmVYnj';

curl $url/coin/address \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -X POST \
  --data '{ "addresses":[ "'$address0'", "'$address1'" ]}'
```

Comment: As per my understanding, it's the api to get UTXOs for multiple addresses. I want to get it for one address only.
Please check this :

address='R9M3aUWCcKoiqDPusJvqNkAbjffLgCqYip';
curl $url/coin/address/$address

Comment: What happens when you perform the req with only that address?

Comment: Also, I want to get the history of UTXOs of this address

Comment: It gives the current balance details of the address

Comment: I see the API you used now. What's your node's sync status?

Comment: Please mark this question solved then :D. 

For transaction history submit another question as it's different from balance checking.